# How to prevent WebApplicationFactory to remove header with empty values?

Tags: c#, integration-testing

When using WebApplicationFactory for testing, I want include a header in the request that contains empty values (it can be *strings*, or *array of strings*).
I have noticed that WebApplicationFactory removes this header when passing the request, I want to avoid this behaviour and force WebApplicationFactory to pass this header.

I create the factory and the client in the setup of the test class:

```
private HttpClient _client;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Setup()
{
   var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
   _client = factory.CreateDefaultClient();
}
```

I send an empty array:

```
[Test]
public async Task Check_Header_With_Empty_Array_OK()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "WeatherForecast");
    var array = Array.Empty<string>();
    request.Headers.Add("X-Test", array);
    var test = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var requestHeaders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(await test.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    Assert.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("X-Test", ""), requestHeaders);
}
```

I debug this request in the controller of the API that I am testing,
and notice that there is no such header:
[image: empty_header]

This doesn't happen when I pass a request it non empty values:

```
[Test]
public async Task Check_Header_With_Non_Empty_Array_OK()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "WeatherForecast");
    var array = new string[] { "one", "two"};
    request.Headers.Add("X-Test", array);
    var test = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var requestHeaders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(await test.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    Assert.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("X-Test", ""), requestHeaders);
}
```

[image: non_empty_header]

How can I prevent WebApplicationFactory to remove the empty header?